# Nested Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

What is wrong with this code, and how can I fix this?
Please explain your answers, so I can learn. I am new to Swift, and fairly new to Programming.

```
var has: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<Dictionary, Int>> = [
    "Material" : [
        "Factory" : 0,
        "Raw" : 0,
        "Energy" : 0,
    ],
    "Workers" : [
        "Dev" : 0,
        "Builder" : 0,
        "Advertiser" : 0,
        "Consultant" : 0,
        "Engenier" : 0,
        "QA" : 0,
    ],
    "Assets" : [
        "Bonds" : 0,
    ],
    "Owe" : [
        "10%" = 0,
        "20%" = 0,
        "30%" = 0
    ],
    "Other" : [
        "Insurance" : 0
    ]
]
```

Comment: Just a note. You can use the alias `[String : [String : Int]]` to represent the type of your dictionary. Much easier to read I think (and easy to spot the error (Dictionary) in your type string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have declared type as `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<Dictionary, Int>>`, but the literal actually is `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Int>>`. Also this is illegal syntax:

```
"Owe" : [
    "10%" = 0,
    "20%" = 0,
    "30%" = 0
],
```

Should be:

```
"Owe" : [
    "10%" : 0,
    "20%" : 0,
    "30%" : 0
],
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, seems to just be that syntax and a silly mistake of mine :)

Comment: Or you could simply omit the explicit type declaration and let the compiler figure it out for you. Just go with `var a = [ ... ]`

Comment: @penne12, please accept the answer by ticking the checkmark next to the answer to turn it green.

Comment: +1 I'd also recommend using the syntax `[String : [String : Int]]` to represent the type of has. Instead of the long-form syntax.